# Load page in div when i click button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net. in my home page i used two image buttons. what should i want to do is when the button click different page need to load in to home page div tag. how can i do it with asp.net /csharp

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: yeah i can do it from php with include command. but i couldn't do it from aspx. that why i am looking for help?. i tried with response.redirect but it open separate page but i need to load same page and div tag with different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an iframe

```
<iframe id="iframe1" ></iframe>
```

Use Js to change the src i.e

document.getElementById('iframe1').src = yourpagepath;

Thanks

Comment: Thx for your help. i wrote this in to my html page. it worked but the thing is i need that src work as a variable. i need to change the src page when my page buttons click.

Comment: can u chk it now..updated the answer

Comment: i have 4 buttons on my page how to identify their click event with these codes. thx

Comment: Use jquery to identify click event.....................$("#buttonid").click(function() {
  alert("clicked");
});

Comment: thx ill try n let u know .

Comment: it did not work . i dont know why.. $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnBusiness").click(function (event) {
                document.getElementById("ihome").src = "resultb.aspx";
               
            });                                                                                                   HTML..                                                                           <iframe      src=""  
            style="z-index: 1; left: -1px; top: 76px; position: absolute; height: 586px; width: 695px" 
            id="ihome"  ></iframe>

Comment: i design my pages from asp.net. i found if i used html buttons outside the form tag its working smoothly but if i design inside the form tag its does not work. Please find me a solution thx